# How to implement TAS ("test and set")?

Tags: c, multithreading, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Did anyone know the implementation of TAS?

This code should later be able to protect the code between acquiring and release from multithread based loss of states.

```
typedef volatile long lock_t;

void acquire(lock_t* lock){
    while(TAS(lock))
        ;
}

void release(lock_t* lock){
    *lock = 0;
}

lock_t REQ_lock = 0;

int main(){
    acquire(&REQ_lock);
    //not Atomar Code
    release(&REQ_lock);
}
```

Comment: Do the  `atomic_compare_exchange` functions from the C11 standard section 7.17.7.4 do what you need?

Comment: There's also the `atomic_flag_test_and_set` operation if you only need something simple and boolean.  Can be found in section 7.17.8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C11 standard brings atomic types into the language.

Among them is the `atomic_flag` type, which has an associated function `atomic_flag_test_and_set`
Here it is from the standard:

C11 working draft section 7.17.8.1:

> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdatomic.h>
> _Bool atomic_flag_test_and_set(
>     volatile atomic_flag *object);
> _Bool atomic_flag_test_and_set_explicit(
>     volatile atomic_flag *object,memory_order order);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> Atomically sets the value pointed to by
>   object
>   to true.  Memory is affected according
>   to  the  value  of
>   order
>   .  These  operations  are  atomic  read-modify-write  operations
>
> **Returns**
>
> Atomically, the value of the object immediately before the effects.

And along with it, you'll want its sister operation, `atomic_flag_clear`

Section 7.17.8.2:

> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdatomic.h>
> void atomic_flag_clear(volatile atomic_flag *object);
> void atomic_flag_clear_explicit(
>     volatile atomic_flag *object, memory_order order);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The order argument shall not be memory_order_acquire nor memory_order_acq_rel. Atomically sets the value pointed to by object to false.
>   Memory is affected according to the value of order.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The atomic_flag_clear functions return no value

Comment: Of course the C11 standard also contains a mutex `mtx_t` and associated functions, so the entire exercise is pointless (and wasteful because busywaiting without control over scheduling is going to kill performance beyond all reason, and scheduling is *not* part of standard C).

Comment: @EOF Yeah, I would agree this is a bit of an X-Y problem.  Depending on what the locks are being used to protect, even Mutices may be too much and simply using atomic types might be a solution on its own.

Comment: @David If you're running on a single-processor machine, building a spinlock will happily deadlock you all the time, unless your OS schedules out the thread (which is not covered by the c standard). Even *if* you have an os (which would almost certainly provide a mutex that does much better than a custom mutex, likely including errorchecking and possibly deadlock detection), you're wasting most of a scheduling interval twidding your thumbs at maximum power consumption. Why?

Comment: @EOF, re, "entire exercise is pointless." Sometimes the point of an exercise is to learn something. There's a lot of useful things you can find in standard libraries these days, and I wouldn't waste my time today re-creating new versions of any of them, but I _did_ create my own versions of pretty much _all_ of them back when I was learning the trade.

Comment: @EOF, Re, "...spinlock..." I fought that fight. Fought against a PhD computer scientist/part owner of a company selling a big-ass, high-performance software system to the U.S. government and some corporations that you have surely heard of. I wanted to get the spinlocks out. I tried N different ways to argue that we should get the spinlocks out. He said, "show me the benchmark." I replaced all the spinlocks with mutexes, I ran real-world benchmarks. He was right. It performed better with spinlocks _in certain, well-chosen places._ If you know what you are doing, there is a use for spinlocks.

Comment: @EOF Spinlocks are worthwhile when you anticipate the wait period will be very short- such as less than a scheduling quantum. This is true both in special systems and can be used in general purpose systems. For example, last time I checked (whew, about 7 years ago) GCC's OpenMP barrier implemention used a hybrid system that would spinwait for a few milliseconds and then fall back to futex waiting. Spinlocks aren't inherently bad. And in fact they could even be used on single processor systems with no OS-level preemption if you had asynchronous memory-mapped hardware, for example.

Comment: @EOF But beyond any specific system rationale, building your own spinlock and experimenting with it is a great exercise for someone wanting to get really deep into parallel or concurrent programming. And at least in my opinion/experience it's an order of magnitude easier than implementing your own blocking mutex.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation must be platform specific, and I would not recommend an assembly, because of its poor code portability. It is better to use **ready-to-go** functions included in target OS. Here is a simple Windows solution:

```
#include <winnt.h>

void acquire(LONG* lock, DWORD bit)
{
    LONG nMask = 1 << bit;
    while (_interlockedbittestandset(lock, bit))
    {
        while (*lock & nMask); // Inner read-only spin
    }
}

void release(LONG* lock, DWORD bit)
{
     _interlockedbittestandreset(*lock, bit);
}

bool try_enter(LONG* lock, DWORD bit)
{
     return !_interlockedbittestandset(*lock, bit);
}

// Usage #1
volatile LONG lockVar = 0;
acquire(&lockVar, 0);
// ... critical code ...
release(&lockVar, 0);

// Usage #2
if (try_enter(&lockVar, 0))
{
     // ... critical code ...
     release(&lockVar, 0);
}
```

You can use different bits (0..31) for different shared objects. The function garantees an atomic operation, [read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-_interlockedbittestandset)

Answer (score -5):

Yeah, no.  One of the virtues of C is to bring you as close to the machine-language boundary as possible, but no further.   This is further.

You could go for atomic support, which is provided in some C augmentation-standard, but is a nest of problems.

Write TAS in assembly. Restrict the visibility of the variables used for TAS, for containment.  For any given architecture, it should be no more than a handful of lines of assembly.  Your program will have contained its dependency, and the lack of containment is amongst the critical flaw in the last decade of C augmentations.

Comment: But there is official support for atomics in the C11 standard.

Comment: It is deeply flawed, as is much of c11.   As a toy implementation, it is pretty good.