# Is there a syscall for test_and_set() instruction?

Tags: system-calls

I'm reading the Silberschatz's book "Operating system". The author talks about the `test_and_set()` instruction and he says that it's an hardware instruction.

I'm pretty curious to understand if exist a system call (in Linux, for example) that allow to use `test_and_set()`.

Comment: The hardware test-and-set instructions are not privileged on most prcessors. You don't need a syscall. Can you provide an example where you think you need a syscall?

Comment: thank you for the answer. But which is the manner to call directly the test-and-set in a program?

Comment: Please share some code and point out where you want to do the test-and-set. Then we can tell you how to do it. I mean, I could tell you that on Alpha AXP, it would be `retry: addl t0, #1, zero; ldl_l t1, 0(v0); bne t1, failed; stl_c t0, 0(v0); bne t0, retry` but if that's not the architecture you're using, then the answer won't be of any use to you. Please provide more details about your target platform and programming language.

Comment: I'm wondering if exist a glibc function that, when compiled, produce machine code that contains the test_and_set() instruction. I'm talking about Linux on x86. My curiosity is about the possibility of "calling"this specific machine instruction using a high level programming language, like C for example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60423882/902497

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement TAS ("test and set")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423594/how-to-implement-tas-test-and-set)